# Apache HTTPD VirtualHost with Proxy to Tomcat and htaccess file not being checked

Tags: apache, tomcat, virtualhost, mod-proxy

I have Apache fronting Tomcat and using *mod_proxy_ajp* to pass requests to Tomcat using the following in the *VirtualHost* config:

```
<Directory "/var/www/mysite">
            Options +Indexes MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
            DirectoryIndex index.jsp
</Directory>

<Proxy balancer://tomcatserversMysite>
            BalancerMember ajp://localhost:8011 route=mysiteA retry=60
</Proxy>
<Location />
            Allow From All
            ProxyPass balancer://tomcatserversMysite/ stickysession=JSESSIONID nofailover=off
</Location>
```

I have a .htaccess file that contains only:

```
deny from all
```

but it does not seem to get read.

Is it possible to get Apache to check the htaccess file before forwarding to the proxy, and if so can anyone suggest where I am going wrong?

Comment: If I add Include /var/www/mysite/.htaccess in the <Location /> and remove the 'Allow From All' then it works but I require a HTTPD restart to pick up the change in the htaccess file which is certainly not ideal if I ever wanted to modify the htaccess on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

As noted above:

> If I add `Include /var/www/mysite/.htaccess` in the `<Location />` and remove the 'Allow From All' then it works but I require a HTTPD restart to pick up the change in the htaccess file which is certainly not ideal if I ever wanted to modify the htaccess on the fly.